# VSCode compatible with rootRequire?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Has anyone been able to get goto def work in a Javascript project that uses [root require](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520)?

I have a project that uses a global root require wrapper to get around having to use relative path imports, but VSCode doesn't play well with this. For reference, WebStorm is able to follow the dependency, but VSCode cannot, so I hope I can just update a setting somewhere to enable this. The wrapper is a follows:

```
global.rootRequire = function(name) {
    return require(__dirname + '/' + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of VS Code 1.19 we do not support `rootRequire`.

To configure VS Code to understand relative import paths, try setting up a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) and configure `"module": "system"`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "system"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```